# why does my html form with php not show all the content?

Tags: php, html, forms

In the form below it only appears the first and second label and the first input type="text". I thought it might be a problem with the second input type text but I have closed it and since the code is similar to the above one which works, I can not seem to find the problem. I have checked for similar problems here but no result. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance for your time.

```
 <form action="perditeso.php?update=tedhenat" method="POST">
    <label>Departamenti:</label><input type="text" maxlength="15" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Dep'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Dep'])); else echo getData($dbc, $userId, 'departamenti'); ?>" name="Dep" /> <br />
    <label>Lenda: </label><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="Kursi" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Kursi'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Kursi'])); else echo getLendet($dbc, $userId); ?>" /> <br />
    <label>Email:</label><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email'])); else echo getData($dbc, $userId, 'email');?>"/> <br />
    <label>Website personal:</label><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="web" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['web'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['web'])); else echo getData($dbc, $userId, 'website'); ?>" /><br /> 
    <label>Adresa: </label><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="add" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['add'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['add'])); else echo getData($dbc, $userId, 'adresa'); ?>" /><br />
    <label>Titulli: </label><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="titulli" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['titulli'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['titulli'])); else echo getData($dbc, $userId, 'titulli'); ?>" /><br />
        <input  type="text" maxlength="15" name="Dep" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Dep'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Dep'])); else echo getData($dbc, $userId, 'departamenti');?>"  />
         <input type="submit" name="nameSubmit3" value="Perditeso"  />
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['update']) && $_GET['update']=="tedhenat")
        {
            $Dep=$_POST['Dep']; 
            $Kursi=$_POST['Kursi'];
             $email=$_POST['email'];
             $web=$_POST['web'];
             $add=$_POST['add'];
            $titulli=$_POST['titulli'];

                if(updateData($userId,$Dep,$email,$web,$add,$titulli,$dbc)){
                    echo "<p id='result'>Data updated!</p>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<p id='result'>There is a problem!";
                    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc);
                   }
                }
```

Comment: Can you please add the raw html output (the one you get from the code in your question) to your question?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yes of course..Here: <label>Departamenti:</label><input type="text" maxlength="15" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Dep'])) echo trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Dep'])); else echo getData($dbc, $userId, 'departamenti'); ?>" name="Dep" /> <br />
 <label>Lenda: </label>

Comment: You are aware that you just posted the same what you have in your question in a comment? Or is that the output (what you see in your browser)? If so, PHP doesn't parse the file, check if the file extension is `.php`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois if you are asking for a photo I think I can not post a photo here :/ The output is: Departamenti: *input type text* than Lenda:

Comment: I am asking for the html source code your browser gets. Copy it and add it to your question (edit your question, don't post it as comment!).

Comment: 1. What is the code on perditeso.php. 2. You are submitting your form with `post` method. How can you receive in `$_GET`.

Comment: @Nitin you are right..new in php and was based on another example. I will imediately check to solve those.

Comment: Use hidden variable to send value `update=tedhenat`. And receive it in $_POST.

Comment: @Nitin it was a problem with the function in the php, 3rd row..If removed, the posted code works fine even with POST and GET..Thank you for your time :)