# Why does the PHP version of an HTML file not show all the elements?

Tags: php, html, css

I am converting a bunch of HTML files into their PHP equivalents for a University assignment gaming site. Currently I have an HTML file called "featured.html" and a php file called "featured.php". I use an echo statement to replicate the content of the html file and use a style.css for styling.
When I open the php file, it  only shows the first 15 or so elements (out of approx 50). All the elements are present when I use the Inspect Element tool but it seems that I cannot scroll down in the php to see all the elements. Why does this happen?

I have looked at the questions [Why does my PHP code not repeat HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060025/why-does-my-php-code-not-repeat-html-elements) and [Why does my form with php not show all the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160420/why-does-my-html-form-with-php-not-show-all-the-content), but couldn't get a satisfactory answer from either.

Below is the original html "featured.html":

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="api-control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Convergence Gaming | Welcome </title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="featuredpage">
            <div class="myGallery">
                <div class="item">
                  <a href="https://www.monsterhunter.com/rise/us/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif" /></a>
                  <span class="caption">Monster Hunter Rise | Dev: Capcom | Genre: Action | Platform: Nintendo | Released: 2012/06/02 </span>
                </div>
<!-- ...there are about 50 of these "item" divs, not the best way of going about it, but I have to build on previous work...-->
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="https://www.callofduty.com/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif"></a>
                    <span class="caption">Call of Duty Cold War | Dev: Activision | Genre: Shooter | Platform: All | Released: 2009/03/01 </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
         </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And below is the featured.php file:

```php
<?php

include './header.php';
include './footer.php';

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="api-control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Convergence Gaming | Welcome </title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="featuredpage">
            <div class="myGallery">
                <div class="item">
                  <a href="https://www.monsterhunter.com/rise/us/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif" /></a>
                  <span class="caption">Monster Hunter Rise | Dev: Capcom | Genre: Action | Platform: Nintendo | Released: 2012/06/02 </span>
                </div>
             <!-- The rest of the echo statement contains the same content as the html and so is omitted -->            <div class="item">
              <a href="https://www.nomanssky.com/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif"></a>
              <span class="caption">No Mans Sky | Dev: Hello Games | Genre: Adventure | Platform: All | Released: 2016/10/09 </span>
            </div>   
        </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html> ';
?>
```

Is there any explanation as to why this would happen? The echo statement contains an exact replica of the html code and all the other styling elements seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no error in this code. Problem is elsewhere. Only problem I see there is no reason for having whole page content in one echo and including footer above doctype...

Comment: Can you identify where the output from PHP stops.  It can help to focus on particular code than just reading large segments of it,

Comment: I'm confused about your ultimate goal. PHP is a templating engine at its core, so you could simply feed raw HTML to the PHP interpreter. Additionally, PHP is a server-side language so the browser will never see it. You just need to inspect the generated output to figure out the differences.

Comment: @pavel I'm doing it like this only becuase we have to replicate a previous assignment but using php. The footer is styled to always be at the bottom of the display

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Well that's the thing, I have compared them in the inspector and they are the same, so I'm wondering whether it isn't maybe a scroll or overflow problem in the styling that's causing issues, but I can't imagine why

Comment: The inspector is not the raw output, that's what the browser has been able to compose from the actual HTML. In some browsers you can see source code with Ctrl+U.

Comment: I've just realised, this doesn't happen when I remove the "include './header.php';" line in the php (which is my page navigation etc). I'll have a quick look what's going on there

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to fix the problem by moving the "include './header.php'" and "include './footer.php'"  to where the header and footer would occur within the html at @pavel's suggestion. I thought that it wouldn't matter since their positions are defined within the style.css, but this was not the case. So the updated featured.php file now looks as follows:

```php
<?php

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="api-control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Convergence Gaming | Welcome </title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    ';
    include './header.php';
    echo '
    <body>
        <section id="featuredpage">
            <div class="myGallery">
                <div class="item">
                  <a href="https://www.monsterhunter.com/rise/us/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif" /></a>
                  <span class="caption">Monster Hunter Rise | Dev: Capcom | Genre: Action | Platform: Nintendo | Released: 2012/06/02 </span>
                </div>
<!-- ... --> 
            <div class="item">
              <a href="https://www.nomanssky.com/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif"></a>
              <span class="caption">No Mans Sky | Dev: Hello Games | Genre: Adventure | Platform: All | Released: 2016/10/09 </span>
            </div>   
        </div>
        </section>
    </body>
    ';
    include './footer.php';
    echo '
</html> ';

?>
```

Comment: This is some very ugly way of rendering such a page... seriously just copy-paste the page , change file extension, and just add your 2 includes with `<?php include 'whatever.php' ?>` where they belong in the otherwise pure html file... There's no point echoing static HTML...

Comment: Their positions are defined in the CSS, but they were printed outside of the html code entirely. CSS still assumes the elements are within the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

### Only use PHP where needed

PHP files can handle mixed output and php tags. Maybe that is not the problem, but can make finding the solution easier.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="api-control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Convergence Gaming | Welcome </title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>

<?php include './header.php'; ?>

        <section id="featuredpage">
            <div class="myGallery">
                <div class="item">
                  <a href="https://www.monsterhunter.com/rise/us/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif" /></a>
                  <span class="caption">Monster Hunter Rise | Dev: Capcom | Genre: Action | Platform: Nintendo | Released: 2012/06/02 </span>
                </div>
                <!-- The rest of the echo statement contains the same content as the html and so is omitted -->
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="https://www.nomanssky.com/"><img src="./img/giphy.gif" /></a>
                    <span class="caption">No Mans Sky | Dev: Hello Games | Genre: Adventure | Platform: All | Released: 2016/10/09 </span>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </section>

<?php include './footer.php'; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

### Is `doctype` the problem?

The only real difference is the declaration of the doctype at the beginning of your PHP code: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. That is probably not your issue..?